# `NIL' is not of the expected type `NUMBER'

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

When I was trying to check the number is equal to any element in list, I get the following error:
`'NIL' is not of the expected type 'NUMBER'`

```
(defun check-num (li n)
  (cond
    ((= n (car li)) t)
    ((not (= n (car li))) (check-num (cdr li) n)) 
    ((not (= n (car li))) nil)))

(check-num '(1 2 3 4 5) 6)
```

I found that the problem occur when it try to excute the function 'check-num' with the empty list with the number entered after perform all checking.

The error come out when the compiler try to perform the following function:

```
(check-num nil 6)
```

Comment: If it is possible your function returns NIL, then use `equal` instead of `=`, it won't fail. (this has been my only bug on deployed application. And I was a lisp newcomer. Pretty nice.)

Answer (score 2):

The immediate problem is that you never check for the end of the list.  The `car` of the empty list is `nil` again.  `=` compares numbers.  `Nil` is not a number.

Check for the end of the list first.  Some minor stylistic issues: when using conses as a list, use `first` and `rest` instead of `car` and `cdr`, name things as they are (`list`), use proper formatting.

```lisp
(defun check-num (list n)
  (cond ((endp list) nil) ; <-
        ((= (first list) n) t)
        (t (check-num (rest list) n))))
```

However, it should be noted that there are several ways already in the standard to achieve this check, e. g.:

```lisp
(member n list)

(find n list)
```